# Stuck On this Database question for Hours

Tags: java, database

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh)
    {



        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {

            try
            {
                long x=sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
                if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");
                if(x>=-32768 && x<=32767)System.out.println("* short");
                if(x>= -2147483648 && x<=((int)Math.pow(2,31))-1)System.out.println("* int");
                if(x>=(-(int)Math.pow(2,63)) && x<=(((int)Math.pow(2,63))-1))System.out.println("* long");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

HELP ME WITH THIS QUESTION ON HACKERANK!

WHY on giving input
1
-100000000000000

OUPUT COMES:-
-100000000000000 can be fitted in:

instead of :-
-100000000000000 can be fitted in:
*long

Comment: Why is this a database question? I can't see any database here.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You have a value for `x` and a question that amounts to "why doesn't this condition to evaluate to true for this x?". Try to think of ways you could find out the answer yourself (debugger? extra prints?), such a skill will be more useful to you in the future than answering challenge puzzles.

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: The whole topic of the question deals with what ranges numerical primitve types have in java. You know that the upper bound of `int` is since you check it against `((int)Math.pow(2,31))-1`. For the `double` range check, you use the expression `((int)Math.pow(2,63))-1)` - you should immediately notice that casting this to an `int` won't work because 2^63-1 does not fit in an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to change your logic like this

```
if(x>= Integer.MIN_VALUE && x<= Integer.MAX_VALUE)System.out.println("* int");
            if(x>=Long.MIN_VALUE && x<=Long.MAX_VALUE)System.out.println("* long");
```

This is not a database-related question, make sure your question is clearer.